# Integer factored mirror numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there any other integer factors rather than 4 or 9 for mirror numbers ?

---

Example of integer factor mirror numbers are:

A)
$1089 * 9 = 9801$ --> mirrored
Also:
$10 9 89$
$10 99 89$
$10 999 89$
$...$

B)
$2178 * 4 = 8712$ --> mirrored
Also:
$21 9 78$
$21 99 78$
$21 999 78$
$...$

---

I don't see any other numbers rather than $1089$ and $2178$ and their combinations with value $9$ or $0$ in middle of them and also other integer factors than $4$ and $9$.

---

Other combinations of these values are:

$1089|1089$
$1089|0|1089$
$1089|00|1089$
$...$

$2178|2178$
$2178|0|2178$
$2178|00|2178$
$...$

But still those are combinations of two values from A and B example

Comment: No, only $4$ and $9$, see [quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-multiplying-a-four-digit-number-by-2-ever-reverse-its-digits-If-yes-then-produce-an-example-If-not-then-prove-it-is-not-possible). See also [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Numbers_Reversed_when_Multiplying_by_9).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot get a reversible number by multiplying with $2,3,5,6,7,8$, see [here](https://orderingchaos.com/reversibleFactor.html).
For example, a reversible number multiplied by $5,6,7,8$ must begin with $1$ and end with the multiplier. But $(1\cdots 5)\cdot 5=5\cdots 5 \neq 5\cdots 1$, $(1\cdots 6)\cdot 6=6\cdots 6 \neq 6\cdots 1$,
$(1\cdots 7)\cdot 7=7\cdots 9 \neq 6\cdots 1$, and
$(1\cdots 8)\cdot 8=8\cdots 4 \neq 8\cdots 1$. However,
for the multipliers $4$ and $9$ it works.

Comment: (1...6)*6 could also be 7...6, or 8...6 or 9...6. This in turn means that the statement "a reversible number multiplied by 5,6,7,8 must begin with 1 and end with the multiplier" is not so obvious: I would say it must begin with 1 and end with a digit greater or equal to the multiplier. There seem to be more cases to check than the linked article says (but I think none of thise cases work and the conclusion is still correct).